# php mysql saving query results

Tags: php, mysql

i have a query that goes like this:

```
            $get_feed_amount = mysql_query("

                SELECT COUNT(*) as num
                FROM `migo_feeds`
                WHERE
                (
                    (
                        feed_type='10' ||
                        feed_type='11' ||
                        feed_type='28' ||
                        feed_type='27' ||
                        feed_type='30' ||
                        feed_type='31'

                    )
                    AND
                    (
                        from_id IN (

                            SELECT DISTINCT from_id
                            FROM `migo_relations`
                            WHERE (
                                (to_id='".$_SESSION['user_id']."')

                                AND

                                (rel_processed='1' AND rel_accepted='1')
                            )                       

                        )

                        OR

                        to_id IN (

                            SELECT DISTINCT from_id
                            FROM `migo_relations`
                            WHERE (
                                (to_id='".$_SESSION['user_id']."')

                                AND

                                (rel_processed='1' AND rel_accepted='1')
                            )                               

                        )

                        OR

                        from_id=".$_SESSION['user_id']."

                        OR

                        to_id=".$_SESSION['user_id']."

                    )
                    AND
                    feed_deleted='0'
                );

            ");
```

as you can see im allready selecting friends twice in this query

and also later i do queries like this:

```
            $migo_groups = mysql_query("

                SELECT 
                    group_id,
                    group_title,
                    group_desc,
                    group_cat_name,
                    group_area,
                    group_city,
                    group_quarter,
                    group_pic,
                    group_tmb,
                    group_members_amount
                FROM
                    `migo_groups`
                WHERE (

                    group_type=1

                    AND

                    group_id IN (

                        SELECT group_id
                        FROM `migo_group_membership`
                        WHERE (

                            membership_type IN (1,2,3)

                            AND

                            to_id IN (

                                SELECT DISTINCT from_id
                                FROM `migo_relations`
                                WHERE (
                                    (to_id='".$_SESSION['user_id']."')

                                    AND

                                    (rel_processed='1' AND rel_accepted='1')
                                )                                   
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
                ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4;
            ");
```

selecting friends once again..
this seems a little bit of waste of resources. Especially if the tables are very large, things will probably take forever to load, or not even load at all.

My question is, can i just do a friend query in the beginning and use the result everywhere? Is that any good at all?

I was thinking perhaps save the resutls in an array or something, is that bad? What would be the best way to run things?

Regards,
Alexander

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the results of the first query in an array and then using only the array for your second need.

Example:

```
$result=array();
$query=mysql_query("SELECT complex sql [...]");
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $result[] = $r;
    /*your first operation here*/
}
```

Now in your result you have all the results of the first query, and you can use that array to do your second operation without the need of other queries.

```
foreach($result as $row) {
      // code
}
```

Also note you should use PDO.

Comment: but is this recommended? i mean i dont know which one is faster, for the php to write out an arra or the database to do a simple friend request query with indexing

Comment: using an array instead to do a query it's up to 10x faster